# How to set image options by Excel VBA Chart.Export

Tags: excel, vba

I want to export charts from Excel sheet in PNG format. VBA Method Chart.Export seems to be the right way.

```
myChart.export filename:=myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
```

Filtername:="PNG" produces PNG-24, but I need  PNG-8 format (in my case it would save about 50 % of file size).
**How can I specify the image format?**

I have tried setting `Interactive` parameter to True, which should "*display the dialog box that contains the filter-specific options*".

```
myChart.export filename:=myFileName, Filtername:="PNG", Interactive:=True
```

Nope. No dialog appears. Even if I set `Fitlername:="JPG"` , no dialog appears.

I have tried set Filtername to "PNG8" a "PNG-8", but these filters does not exist.

Is there a way how to influence image settings?
And how can I get the list of allowed filters? (official documentation is: *The language-independent name of the graphic filter as it appears in the registry.*)

Comment: Tbh, I think `Chart.Export` is buggy... `Interactive` doing nothing is detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131924/export-excel-chart-to-svg-creates-an-empty-file).

Comment: Export it as png - 24 and then use the [batch file in Command-line - Binary for Windows section](https://pngquant.org/) from VBA to convert it to PNG - 8.